# Activiti JS how create FromData in .bpmn20.xml using Nashorn(JDK 8)

Tags: activiti, bpmn, business-process-management, nashorn

I tried to use js in .bpmn20.xml. Now I know, that using JDK 8, I am using Nashorn JavaScript engine. But how can I create new FormData in JS with Nashorn? 
I tried, like that:

```
var data = new org.activiti.engine.form.FormData();
```

but get error: `Cannot create new object with constructor org.activiti.engine.form.FormData.`

What is the right way to create FormData? And with Nashorn can I use normal JS code? How to load a package which need to JS?
Before is was simply use Rhino in older JDK.

Actually in future I want to create XMLHttpRequest and send POST request to REST server.

Sorry for a lot of questions and thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "org.activiti.engine.form.FormData" a java class? is that in a jar file? if so, you may want to put that in classpath for jjs tool [assuming you're using jjs tool to run the code] or app's classpath [assuming you use javax.script to evaluate scripts].

Comment: yes, I already did it, and one more thing, is it possible to load my own js script in .bpmn? I tried tu use load("my.js") but it doen`t work.